# Sourcing from netlify cms

Tags: gatsby, netlify-cms

I followed the tutorial on Gatsby's site. I have the 'hello world' https://admiring-bose-8807f8.netlify.com/ site running. I've created a post but stuck getting it to show. I'm using the gatsby-source-filesystem plugin. My gatsby-config.js file is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  /* Your site config here */
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `blog`,
        path: `${__dirname}/blog`
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
    ]
}
```

and my config.yml is

```
backend:
  name: github
  repo: jamesgrubb/Gatsbycms

media_folder: static/assets
public_folder: assets

collections:
  - name: blog
    label: Blog
    folder: blog
    create: true
    fields:
      - { name: path, label: Path }
      - { name: date, label: Date, widget: date }
      - { name: title, label: Title }
      - { name: body, label: Body, widget: markdown }
```

When I get in to the admin and click to create a new post I have the following fileds

- Path
- Date
- Title
- Body

I have input the following strings:

- Path: /first-blog/
- Date: (pre-filled)
- Title: Title
- Body: Lorem ipsum

How should I be formatting my URL? I've tried:
https://admiring-bose-8807f8.netlify.com/blog/first-blog/Title

no joy?

Any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check out your repo on github & I think you've missed the part where you have to query for the markdown files and then render them in `gatsby-node.js`. Checkout this [official tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-seven/) or inspect the [official blog starter source](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog/blob/master/gatsby-node.js).